# symfony workflow component and announce event

Tags: symfony, symfony-workflows

I just discovered a problem in my application because of the announce event
https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow.html#using-events

the documentation says :

> if you don't need the announce event, disable it using the context

Can someone explain me why it is not disabled by default and what is the goal of testing each next transition ?